# TFS 2013 Team Rooms not reporting events (anymore)

Tags: tfs

We have been using TFS 2013 for over a year now and have been using the Team Rooms (basically an IRC clone) without any problems.  Additionally, I set up an automated build of our main project whenever anyone checks in a change.  I then configured the Team Room to post a notification in the chat room whenever a build completed.  Everyone appreciates this feature because it lets us know that there is a new update, and it lets us know if there is a problem compiling the current code base, usually prompting ridicule of the poor fool for being so careless.

Unfortunately, I recently took a two week vacation and while I was gone the Team Room *stopped* reporting build completions.  Everyone claims there were no changes.  I am the senior dev and the junior guys don't have access to the server anyway.  I have verified in the "Manage events..." dialog that the room is still configured to post a notification when a build is completed, and I have been unable to find any trouble shooting guides on where else to look.

Is there a service I should be looking for?  An error log somewhere?  Has anyone else seen something like this?

Comment: Did you try to recreate the team room?

Comment: @ds19 Yes, new rooms also do not display build events

Comment: Check the server event log.